# trouble running ipython -qtconsole on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ipython

When I try to run qtconsole from a terminal the program loads, i get the little intro text. but i am unable to use the console. At the bottom, where the input should be, I get,

```
[TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization:
[TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | Unrecognized flag: '-qtconsole'
```

Has anyone encountered this problem or have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: have you installed the pyqt from http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download ?

Comment: Trying that now, ill let you know what happens.

Comment: nothing, I already had it installed.

Comment: Uninstalled and reinstalled, fixed! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `ipython -qtconsole`, it's `ipython qtconsole` (no `-`). The various IPython entry points (qtconsole, notebook, etc.) are 'subcommands', so just spaces between words, no leading `-`.  Those are only for command-line options that change behavior, such as `ipython --no-color` or `ipython qtconsole --matplotlib qt`.

Comment: I see this now in version 4, how can I get the same black background on OSX? thanks